# how to update different Partial view using one ajax call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-partialview, ajaxform

[image]

In  above image when double click on **div(First Image)** then **View dialog box(second Image)** both case content printed same data but  structure is different.

controller

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult FirstParialView(long ID)
  {
      //inserted some data into database Here

    List<TimetableDetails> timetableObs =unitofWork.TimetableDetails.ToList();
     return PartialView("DayStructure/_FirstView", timetableObs);
  }   

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult SecondParialView(long ID)
  {
    List<TimetableDetails> timetableObs =unitofWork.TimetableDetails.ToList();
     return PartialView("DayStructure/_SecondView", timetableObs);
  }
```

Ajax call (This Ajax design and  work in dialog box)

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("FirstParialView", "timetable", new { area = "User" },
                        new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "ViewMPlan"))
{
      //Inserted Some data using submit button here. and view both parial view
}
```

javascript

```
 function ViewMPlan(response) {
   //print first Parial View
   $('#firstParialView').html(response);
  //for second parial view
    $.ajax({
                url: "/user/timetable/SecondParialView",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: { ID: ID},
                success: function (response) {
               $('#SecondParialView').html(response);
          }
        });
    }
```

In  above case I have to seperate ajax call for second parial view actual it gets same data .

Is this possible to update both parial View using just Single Call like just Only calling **FirstParialView**

Comment: Not if your returning partial views from your controller methods. You need to make 2 calls. In order to restrict it to one call, you would need to return a `JsonResult` of all the properties/values you need and then update the DOM (potentially a lot of extra code in your view, which will be difficult to test and maintain, for what will probably be only a small improvement in performance).

Comment: I would recommend that you get rid of `Ajax.BeginForm()` and just use the `$.ajax()` methods for both calls, which also means you can make both calls at the same time rather that waiting for the 1st to complete before makeing the 2nd

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok fine then I have to use two call for this . I searched for this topic so I got one link which showed me one way  Please check this https://rhamesconsulting.com/2014/10/27/mvc-updating-multiple-partial-views-from-a-single-ajax-action/   I donot  know its good or not

Comment: Yes, that is another possibility :)

Comment: but its good regarding performance or not

Comment: It would improve performance because (1) your saving having to establish an extra connection with the server and (2) you only calling your database method once. How much that is, only you can test :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You you can indeed do this what i do is that i'v created a function which will render my partial views inside a variable, like this

```
private string RenderPartialView(string viewName, object model)
        {
            ViewData.Model = model;
            using (System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter())
            {
                ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
                ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, writer);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, writer);

                return writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
```

now you need to change your action result something like

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AjaxCallFunc(long ID)
{
List<TimetableDetails> timetableObs =unitofWork.TimetableDetails.ToList();
var partialView1 = RenderPartialView("DayStructure/_FirstView", timetableObs);
var partialView2 = RenderPartialView("DayStructure/_SecondView", timetableObs);
return Json(new{View1=partialView1,View2=partialView2 },JsonRequestBehaviour.DenyGet);
}
```

and then your controller to

```
unction ViewMPlan(response) {
   //print first Parial View
   $('#firstParialView').html(response);
  //for second parial view
    $.ajax({
                url: "/user/timetable/AjaxCallFunc",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: { ID: ID},
                success: function (response) {
                $('#FirstPartialView').html(response.View1);
               $('#SecondParialView').html(response.View2);
          }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I got solution with help of  @StephenMuecke.

Comment: Is this line  $('#firstParialView').html(response); needed

Comment: @Pravin ya i seen that but there is an issue in that for your case since your partial view is interacting with db therefor it will send unnecessary calls to db here you are requesting for the same data in both partial views but the answer i provided will give you a better performance

Comment: @Pravin ya since you are rendering two views you need to show them somwhere dont you??

Comment: its worked for me  with help of this link  https://rhamesconsulting.com/2014/10/27/mvc-updating-multiple-partial-views-from-a-single-ajax-action/